# Passing a variable from javascript back to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, argument-passing

I'm passing variables back to html, and for pictures or links, its working fine.. But i want just the "text" of the 'username' field to show.  Here's what my javascript is doing:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var ncode = '<div id="box"><div id="box.mainimg"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+data[i].thumb+'"></a></div><div id="box.footer"><img src="'+data[i].avatar+'"><a href="'+data[i].profilelink'" target="_"blank">"'+data[i].username'"</a></div></div>';
                $(container).append(ncode);
            });
```

It passes the .thumb, .avatar, as photos just fine, but when i go to link the user's actual name (which is clickable to the URL) it errors out.  I'm sure its a simple one, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: one more thing, instead of using `data[i]` you can simply use `item.url`, `item.username`, `item.thumb` and `item.profilelink`

Comment: You forgot to add a `+` at the end of the username  and profilelink

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). You can actually see if you have a syntax error by opening the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing '+' symbol at the end while appending the variables data[i].profilelink, data[i].username. Also you can directly access the element using `item` inside the loop like below.

```
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var ncode = '<div id="box"><div id="box.mainimg"><a href="'+item.url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+item.thumb+'"></a></div><div id="box.footer"><img src="'+data[i].avatar+'"><a href="'+item.profilelink+'" target="_"blank">"'+item.username+'"</a></div></div>';
        $(container).append(ncode);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that playing the "find the difference" game is going to be very useful for the OP.

Comment: I saw that error, so thanks for that. But the problem is when i put : <a href="'+item.profilelink+'" target="_"blank">"'+item.username+'"</a>  all that is outputted on the page is the quotes, no text.  How do i get that text to display?

Comment: Ok never mind, had a variable string wrong. thanks for the helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a `+` at the end of the username  and profilelink

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var ncode = '<div id="box"><div id="box.mainimg"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+data[i].thumb+'"></a></div><div id="box.footer"><img src="'+data[i].avatar+'"><a href="'+data[i].profilelink+'" target="_"blank">"'+data[i].username+'"</a></div></div>';
                $(container).append(ncode);
        });
```

Comment: I saw that error, so thanks for that. But the problem is when i put : <a href="'+item.profilelink+'" target="_"blank">"'+item.username+'"</a> all that is outputted on the page is the quotes, no text. How do i get that text to display?